# Jpanel doesn't draw when another class is loaded

Tags: java, swing, class, focus, jpanel

I know exactly what line is causing the problem, but there are no stack trace errors being shown, so I'm left with debugging. The problem that has got me is that I thought the panel didn't have focus. When first opened, the panel is blank, and not drawn, but when I minimize and restore, the panel gets painted. I tried adding `panel.requestFocus()` and `panel.requestFocusInWindow()` to the constructor of the class that is being initialized before the screen is painted, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Here is the code:

JPanel class:

```
package blackjack;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Board extends JPanel {
    int dealer = 0;
    int player = 0;
    int money = 2500;
    Deck deck;
    Player p = new Player();
    public Board() {
        deck = new Deck(false, this); //if I comment this out, the panel gets painted straight away
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());


        repaint();
    }
}
```

And the class that is causing the problem:

```
package blackjack;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Deck {
    Card[] deck = new Card[52];
    int[] used = new int[52];
    Random r = new Random();
    public Deck(boolean shuffle, Board b) {
        int i = 0;
        for(int x=0; x<51; x++) {
            used[x] = -1;
        }
        for(Cards card : Cards.values()) {
            if(card.getId() != 53) {
                Image image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(card.getImagePath())).getImage();
                deck[i] = new Card(card.getId(),card.getValue(),image);
                i = i+1;
            }
        }
        if(shuffle) shuffle();
        b.requestFocus();
        b.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    public void shuffle() {
        Card[] shuffled = new Card[52];
        for(int x=0; x<51; x++) {
            int i = pickNotUsed();
            if(i==-1) break;
            shuffled[x] = deck[i];
        }
        deck = shuffled;
    }
    private int pickNotUsed() {
        int notpicked = r.nextInt(52);
        for(int x=0; x<51; x++) {
            if(used[x] != notpicked) {
                return notpicked;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public Card[] getCards() {
        return deck;
    }
    public Card drawCard() {
        for(int x=0; x<deck.length; x++) {
            if(deck[x] != null) {
                return deck[x];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

original class, extends JFrame
    package blackjack;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Blackjack extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Blackjack();
    }
    public Blackjack() {
        setSize(1000,600);
        setTitle("Blackjack");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        add(new Board());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overriding `paint` and calling `paintComponent` in it's body and then `repaint`. Do not do that stuff, in the `Board` class. `repaint` inside the `paint/paintComponent` will result in infinite recursive paint calls (which in actual will get colaesed, meaning only that repaint request will be entertained which is in the queue, when others arrived). Instead just override `paintComponent` for the `JPanel` along with `getPreferredSize` to return some valid `Dimension` object, and make `super.paintComponent` as the first line.

Comment: Yep. Override `paintComponent(...)` and call the `super.paintComponent(g)`. Don't call `repaint()` from inside of it. There won't be a true recursion, but it's still a very bad way to animate.

Comment: @nIcEcOw: yep just saw the parameter...

Comment: sorry, I didn't mention, repaint() was added to debug. The error was there before I added repaint(). But either way, the painting works without the Deck class being initialized, but if it is initialized, painting doesn't occur until after I minimize and restore the frame.

Comment: Where is your JFrame? How are you displaying this? When do you call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame? Before or after adding components?

Comment: The jframe is the original class.
I'll edit the OP

Comment: Don't override `paint(...)`, instead override `paintComponent(...)`. Read the JComponent API to see its signature.

Comment: Ahh. You mentioned where I added the setVisible() and add(new Board()) methods, I swapped them and it worked. thanks

Comment: Where is the `Card` class? Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so that one can try their hands on it :-) Do not just extend a class for the sake of using it (only do so when you need to add more features to it)

Comment: @Levi : And Please do read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), seems like you missing this part too, in the code provided so far :-) In simple terms change the main method to something like `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {new Blackjack();}});`

Comment: I'll read up on Concurrency, but the error was fixed when Hovercraft Full of Eels asked about the setvisible() method.

Answer (score 0):

- Add components to your JFrame (Board) before showing it.
- Don't override *paint* method, instead put you drawing logic to *[paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29)*:

> A subclass that just wants to specialize the UI (look and feel) delegate's paint method should just override paintComponent.

- There is no need to call *repaint()* in *paint* method as it will cause endless loop. *Paint* method is called automatically by the system when it needs to be repainted or by you when you do actually need to repaint it.
- Don't do **requestFocus** untill you really understand the behaviour. In this case there is no point calling it.

Anyway, even in this state you application shows me the green background frame from the start.